# SARIMA plot_diagnostic does not show the white noise of standardized residual for "E"

Tags: statsmodels

I am trying to use plot_diagnostics on my SARIMA model but the standardized residual is not showing any white noise and is a completely straight line.

```
pred_in_sample = arima_model.fittedvalues
pred_out_sample = arima_model.forecast(steps=len(test_data))

# Reindex pred_in_sample to align with the index of train_data
pred_in_sample = pred_in_sample.reindex(train_data.index)

# Concatenate the aligned pred_in_sample and pred_out_sample
pred_full = np.concatenate((pred_in_sample, pred_out_sample))

# Plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 5))
ax.plot(train_data['Water Consumption (tons)'], label='training')
ax.plot(test_data['Water Consumption (tons)'], label='testing')
ax.plot(energy_df.index, pred_full, label='prediction', color='green')
plt.legend()
plt.title('ARIMA Model for Water Consumption (tons)')
plt.show()

# To evaluate the ARIMA model
mape_train = mean_absolute_percentage_error(train_data['Water Consumption (tons)'], pred_in_sample)
mape_test = mean_absolute_percentage_error(test_data['Water Consumption (tons)'], pred_out_sample)
print(f'Model Mean Absolute Percentage Error on training data is {mape_train*100:.2f}%')
print(f'Model Mean Absolute Percentage Error on testing data is {mape_test*100:.2f}%')
```

[The residuals are a completely straight line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1hMP.png)

I have tried tuning my hyperparameters using models that produce worse AIC & BIC results to prevent overfitting but that also does not seem to change anything.